# The Expression assigned to X must be constant

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, constants

I'm having this problem and searching for solutions, but didn't find a situation similar to mine.Here's what I have:

in a class file X.cs:

```
namespace BlaBla{

  public class X{
    public const string foo = "foo";
    // other code
  }

  public class Y{
    public const int bar = 0;
  }
}
```

and in some other class, I'm writing:

```
private const string someString = X.foo + Y.bar + "";
```

it keeps giving me a compile error:

`The Expression assigned to someString must be constant`

although they are both constant! when I remove Y.bar the error is removed and I dont know why. Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `const` keyword wrong. You probably want to define `someString` as:

```
private readonly someString = X.foo + Y.bar;
```

When a variable is marked as `const` they are compiled in to the assembly and then optimised. While `Y.bar` is defined as `const`, you're implicitly invoking its `ToString()` method which makes it not constant.

Answer (score 3):

You're including a conversion from `int` to `string`. Even though the `int` is a constant, the conversion isn't considered a constant expression.

You can demonstrate that more simply:

```
class Test
{
    const int X = 10;
    const string Y = "X: " + X;
}
```

See section 7.19 of the C# specification for more details about what counts as a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

The expression looks constant, but it requires evaluation so that value can be figured out.